# Boost Serialization – Avoid string length output?

Tags: c++, boost-serialization

I'm serializing some data coming off of two different branches of a project. The data is outputted in text archive form using `boost::serialization`. Since a diff is to be made between the two serialized files, I'm also adding some debug messages into the serialized files between each serialized part, as to better see the point at which a difference in the output may occur.

Here is a broad overview of the code I'm currently using:

```
std::ofstream ofs("./SomeFile.txt"); // for brevity's sake, no actual path used
{
  boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
  std::string debug_str;

  debug_str = "\n\nPart 1\n";
  oa & debug_str;

  // ... some other serialized parts ...

  debug_str = "\n\nPart 145\n";
  oa << debug_str;
}
```

You can notice that I first thought that the used operator (`&` vs `<<`) made a difference in output, yet it doesn't, I get the following text file :

```
22 serialization::archive 7 9 [CRLF]
[CRLF]
Part 1 [CRLF]
 11 [CRLF]
[CRLF]
Part 145 [CRLF]
```

The `22 serialization::archive 7` part is a standard Boost serialization header, identifying the type of archive I guess. Afterwards comes the part I would like to have removed, namely `9` – after a bit of goose chasing I figured out that the `9` is the length of the `"\n\nPart1\n"` string!

Is this expected behaviour or is there a way of circumventing this output? In the case of other actual records, there is no apparent use of other such "control codes", marking length or such.

It would be useful to add some debug output, yet because the lengths of the said debug strings may differ (since heavy refactoring occured on one of the branches), the diff yields some false positives.

Any thoughts would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt this is possible.

The problem you face here is that the textual output need be *parsed back* to be deserialized. There are two main ways of structuring textual output so it can be parsed back easily:

- length-prefixed strings
- special characters (with escape codes)

For example, in an xml archive the tags are surrounded with `<` and `>` and you cannot use those characters yourself, instead using escaped codes `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively. On the other hand, if you look at the Redis format you will see things like `13$Hello, World!` where the length of the record is a string of digits, followed by $, followed by the actual record.

The former way (length-prefixed strings) is much more efficient, but much less human writable.

From the Boost::Serialization documentation, I see two different "human-readable" archives:

- `boost::text_[i/o]archive` uses the length-prefixed string (it seems)
- `boost::xml_[i/o]archive` uses the xml representation

You might want to switch to `boost::xml_oarchive`.

Comment: I got bitten by way too many errors related to switching to an XML Archive, will have to live with those string lengths after all.

Comment: Did you try to insert the string char by char? The length is needed so that you may deserialize a string, i.e. you need to know the size. If you DO know the size you may serialize/deserialize 9 chars. then the size should not be present.

Comment: if you need more "general" approach without the size output you may introduce a new type that is size dependent - i.e. template <int N> class mystr; with custom serialization that will serialize N chars... The type will be deduced implicitly upon deserialization and you will deserialize N chars. Didn't try this though just an idea.

Comment: @typical: I would advise against it, it plagues backward/forward compatibility and is particularly inefficient if the maximum size is much higher than the average size.

Comment: Addition of every new type to serialization plaues backward/forward compatibility, so this problem is valid as a general rule. It may cost efficiency for the operator& call for each char but apart from that what kind of inefficiency are you reagarding? of course I do not think this is a great approach, unless really needed but removing the size is definitely possible.

Comment: @typical: I was talking about the inefficiency when the maximum size of the string is much higher than its average size. Because, in average, you encode `max(string) - avg(string)` useless bytes.

Comment: Of course you could stop upon null byte in such case... anyways, I also don't recommend this. One size value is generally not worthed the effort.